# How do I use a component's property inside a parent abstract class?

Tags: angular, typescript

Abstract Class:

```
export abstract class AbstractClass {
  constructor();

  method() {
    // how to use SomeComponent's name input here;
  }
}
```

Component:

```
export class SomeComponent extends AbstractClass {
    @Input() name: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

How do I use `SomeComponent's` name input value inside `AbstractClass's` method?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the property in the `AbstractClass`

```js
export abstract class AbstractClass {
  name: string;
...
}
```

Declare name in the child class using `override` - this is just a typescript keyword that ensures the parent class contains the same property.

```js
@Input() override name: string;
```

Use the property with `this.name` in the parent class

```js
  method() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
```

Call the method in the child class

```js
export class SomeComponent extends AbstractClass {
    @Input() override name: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.method()
    }
}
```